# How to get real CAPTCHA images with python selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, captcha

I'm trying to solve a sliding CAPTCHA on `https://beian.miit.gov.cn`. I want to save the image as a local file and run some edge detection algorithm on it to obtain the correct offset, but the image is not given by a url (maybe it's a javascript? `src="data:text/javascript;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAA...`). How can I download the image?

I should probably change the problem title, but I'm not sure how to describte my problem in a more technical way.

Here is the code that gives the background image:

```
<img data-v-8408b814="" id="bgImg" width="500px" src="data:text/javascript;base64,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" alt="" style="height: 190px; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
```

Comment: I don't think you'll have much luck with this. Try finding a captcha solver chrome extension instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What you are doing does not seem morally correct.
2. The source of the image is base64, with python you can decode it and save it as a file:

### EDIT: Here is the code working:

```
import base64

encoded_string = yourElement.get_attribute('src').replace('data:text/javascript;base64,', '')
decoded_string = base64.b64decode(encoded_string)

with open('captcha.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(decoded_string)
```

output: [image: Captcha Image]

Comment: I just googled Base64 and the src content makes sense to me now. Btw, what would you suggest I do next? Thanks

Comment: You had to remove the malformations from the beginning "data:text/javascript;base64," and then encode it in its format (JPG). Check the code I've updated now.